# Center image over a div like wordpress thumbnail

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Wordpress uses a function to center completely the image on a thumbnail when you are editing a post so it look like this when i´m editing the post:

[image]

i´m trying to show the image that way on a wordpress page but I don´t know how to create a function like the one that uses wordpress to do that:

```
$s_x = floor( ($orig_w - $crop_w) / 2 );
$s_y = floor( ($orig_h - $crop_h) / 2 );
```

So this is how it looks in my page:

[image]

it just shows from the top, so it cuts the image, no center or resize

this is my markup:

```
            echo '<div class="aimagediv" >'; //        
            echo '<img src="'.$s['project_image'].'" alt="" width="270" />';
            echo '</div>';
```

i´m limiting the width just to show something, i know it´s wrong to do it that way, that´s why i´m looking for a function to rezise and center the image over the div.

Can someone help me with this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're better to put this image as a background image of the div and then using css to change background-size to cover and then background-position to center...

**HTML**

```
echo '<div class="image" style="background-image:url(\''.$s['project_image'].'\');">';

echo '</div>';
?>​
```

**CSS**

```
.image{
width: 270px;
height: 270px;
background-size:cover;
background-position: center;
}​
```

Here's a jsfiddle showing it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jhu2Y/

Comment: I don´t think I can work it that way since it´s always a different image that gets from the post of wordpress

Comment: you can define the background image in the div, I'll edit my post

Comment: I cleaned the cache, the errors still there and it doesn´t load any images, it looks like it search the images in a bad way: webkunst.comeze.com/errors.png.

Comment: try the code now, maybe its just the `"´ that are causing the issue

Comment: yeah, it worked now and it centered the images !!!! exactly what I needed, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

will this div have any other content besides the image? you could use CSS to define a height/width for the div and set the image as a background image with a background size of cover... like this:

** EDIT -- Adding PHP tags before and after since the OP was using echo **

```
<?php
    // do all the php code here that you want before the image div
?>

<style type="text/css">
div.aimagediv {
    height:270px;
    width:270px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
}
div.aimagediv:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
</style>

<div class="aimagediv" style="background-image:url('<?=$s['project_image']?>');"></div>

<?php
    // do the rest of your php stuff here
?>
```

Then if you want to make the div clickable you could use an onclick like this: (replace the div line above with this one)

```
<div class="aimagediv" style="background-image:url('<?=$s['project_image']?>');" onclick="window.location='page_id=42&slide=<?=$i?>';"></div>
```

Comment: keep in mind i´m using echo, it´s not just a div, I don´t I can add the style to the echo of div, this give me error. I guess it´s because i´m using the echo before :)

Comment: In PHP you can output HTML without echo if you close out of your PHP tag and then write you HTML and then open up a new PHP tag if you want more PHP code. I used shorthand PHP tags inside the HTML to account for the PHP variables he used. I will edit my answer to make this more clear...

Comment: I just don't like doing echos of large chunks of HTML. To me it is more clear if you exit the php code block and put plain html (with php shorthand where necessary).

Comment: thank you, it looks very clear your explanation and works also

Comment: Why not? `echo '<div class="aimagediv" style="background-image:url("'. $s["project_image"] . '"); >';`

Comment: @dunc -- that would work fine, I just wanted the example to be consistent and since I was going to include how to make it clickable (with the onclick), that would have been a really long echo. It's really just a matter of preference. Also, what about the style block? should we use echo for that all as well?

Comment: @mason81 sorry, let me explain. your example is how I'd do it too - I was referring to diego's comment about `I don't think I can add the style to the echo of the div` but a number of other comments had appeared by the time I hit "Add Comment"!.

Comment: @dunc -- ah, ok that makes sense, thanks for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's container probably has a limited height. So When you set the only witdh, it will stretch the image to fit that width, maintaining the aspect ratio.
If you set only the height, it's the other way around.
If you set both width and height it will stretch the image to fit those bounds (and thus maybe screw up the aspect ratio.
So in your case, set the height, or set both (but make sure you got the ratio right)

if you want the image to center relative to it's container, use CSS to set the left and right margin to auto